Problem exceeding maximum token in azure openai (with java)
I'm doing a chat that returns queries based on the question you ask it in reference to a specific database.
For this I use azure openai and Java in Spring Boot.

My problem comes here:
How can I make the AI remember the previous questions without passing the context back to it
(what I want to do is greatly reduce the consumption of tokens, since depending on what it asks,
if the question contains a keyword, for example 'users',
what I do is pass in the context the information in this table that is huge
(name of the fields, type of data and description)
so when you have several questions the use of tokens rises to more than 10,000))
I can't show all the code since it's a project for my company.
What im currently doing is adding to the context the referenced table and the principal context(you are a based SQL chat...).
And for the chat to remember, I have tried to save the history in java and pass the context history again(but this exceed the tokens pretty fast)
This is what I'm currently doing (no remembering from the AI):
chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.SYSTEM, context));
chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER, question));
ChatCompletions chatCompletions = client.getChatCompletions(deploymentOrModelId,
new ChatCompletionsOptions(chatMessages));

I think you need to learn how to use markdown to format your posts. By the way, it's I'm (which is short for I am) - and not im.

As far as I know, there is no way to make the LLM (Azure OpenAI in this case) remember your context cheaply, as you said, sending context (and a huge chunk of it) on each call gets pricy really fast. That been said, you could change the approach and try other techniques to mimic that the AI has memory like summarizing the previous questions and send that as content (instead of a long string with 20 questions/answers, you send a short summary of what the user has been asking for. it will keep your prompt short and kind of "aware" of the conversation.
There are also conversation buffers (keeping the chat history in memory and send it to de llm each time as you did) but it gets long pretty fast, for that you could configure a buffer window (limiting the memory of the conversation to the last 3 questions for example, that should help keep the token count manageable).
There are several ways to manage this but there is no "perfect memory" as far as I know, not one the is worth paying. If you could tell us a bit more on how good the bot memory needs to be or the specific use case, maybe we can be more precise. Good luck!
here are some references that you could use to start:

Generative AI 101: Making your LLM context-aware using LangChain
Crazy idea: Put all history in a document and use RAG so retrieve the relevant parts of the conversation only


Thank you Diego, the references that you post unfortunately are for LangChain that its a library of python, and im using Java. But I think I'm going to catch the main ideas and aproach the problem limiting the memory of the conversation to the last 3 questions as you said. Very helpfull, thanks

Just ran across this; haven't tried it myself yet. https://github.com/langchain4j/langchain4j
